# How to model the fastest gain of contiguous area above a certain value?

Tags: qgis, cost-path, modelling, habitat-modeling, least-cost

Imagine you have a grid of squares with values 1 to 10.
Some squares are "available", and some are "unavailable", and must be "gained".
Each step you can only gain squares with a total value of 20.
How can you sequence or model the fastest way to accumulate squares that have a value of 10?

See the diagram in the image.

[image]

I would want each feature to have a number for the order it would be obtained. For example, a square might have a value of 457 as the 457th square that is accumulated.

The application of this is to create a model of the expansion of cougar habitat through "rewilding". We have values of habitat suitability, and I want to expand and connect polygons above a certain value.

Ideally we can do this in QGIS, but ArcGIS or other tools are okay.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck? Offering two/more different platforms means this doesn't conform to the One question per Question policy.  Please [Edit] this Question.

Comment: I'm saying you can give a solution with one or the other, not for both:
"Ideally we can do this in QGIS, but ArcGIS or other tools are okay."
If that's not good, I'll just delete the sentence.

Comment: Also - I've done nothing for this. I have no idea where to begin. I know there's something like "Least Cost Path", but I think this is a bit different.

Comment: GIS SE is a *problem-solving* site. We don't work as well for primary research as for a specific error. In theory, [Chat] would work for brainstorming solutions, but in practice, Chat just doesn't get the visitor volume to make it worthwhile.